# How to set up source mapping using 'V8 debugger for node' in Eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to set up a source map to prevent Eclipse from popping up that *"Select Source File"* every time I hit a breakpoint with the **V8 debugger for node** plugin using **Eclipse Mars**.

The popup asks me to *"Choose a source file"*

- `myFile.js` `/myProject/app`
- `myFile.js.chromium` `/New_configuration`

The first one is my physical file inside the `app` directory in my `myProject` project.

The second one is the temporary directory in the Project Explorer named after the debug configuration, that appears every time the debugger is run.

Now I have a source mapper from `/var/www/nodejs/project` (parent of the physical `app` directory) to `myProject`. This is what I had in **Eclipse Kepler**, and I would always directly break in my local script.

In **Eclipse Mars**, it seems the popup offering the temporary `.js.chromium` file as an alternative just always shows up.

How do I properly set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Just try http://www.nodeclipse.org/ then you don't need to configure anything to start debugging.

Nodeclipse comes with modified version of Chrome Dev Tools, so if you need to have both ways, install in other Eclipse instance or get Nodeclipse package like Enide (Studio) 2015 http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/2015/

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Nodeclipse-1-debugging.png))</sub>